# Mod_rewrite Help

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is what I have, but it is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]
RewriteRule ^location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews/$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]
```

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

http://www.example.com/this-location-1234/reviews/ to http://www.example.com/location.php?purl=this-location-1234&page=review

Comment: What is not working? And how did you expect it works?

Comment: trying to rewrite the URL above. I am getting a "Not Found" error. Updated post.

Comment: You forgot the `/location/…` in your example URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I accidentally was missing some verbiage in the link I was getting an error on.

`RewriteRule ^location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews/?$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]`

This works great!

Answer (score 1):

You should combine those two (nearly identical) rules, and make sure you have the `RewriteEngine on` and your rule is being run (either your .htaccess is getting picked up, or you have this in an active vhost definition).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews/?$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for the example URLs you given:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews/?$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]
```

(replace the two rewrite rules with this one)

If you don't already have one, add `RewriteEngine on` before this RewriteRule.

If you actually wanted to rewrite `/location/this-location-1234/reviews/` instead of `/this-location-1234/reviews/`, then use this:

```
RewriteRule ^location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reviews/?$ location.php?purl=$1&page=reviews [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have another property in your conf file called RewriteEngine on ?
Also, you can turn on the logging with RewriteLogLevel.

Comment: Yes, I have rewrite on. Let me turn on Logging to see if I can figure it out.